# Goldbach conjecture and the difference of two primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

The Goldbach conjecure is not yet proved. But, when an even number is represented as a sum of two primes, is there any knwon result about the difference of the two primes?

That is, if $2n$ is a sum of two primes, then can we choose primes $p$ and $q$ such that $2n = p+q$ and the differene $p-q$ is bounded by some formula about $n$?

It is clear that the difference is not bounded by a constant, because consecutive composite numbers can be made to be arbitrarily long.

Comment: As a first heuristic, if we start at $p = q = n$ and walk outwards, the expected time to hit primes would be $O(\log^2 n)$.  So an upper bound is probably that plus another $\log \log n$ factor?

Comment: Almost certainly there are no actually proven results in this direction. But one can ask for heuristics, or about what is known for most numbers (since we know Goldbach holds for most even numbers, I imagine results of this sort might be available).

Comment: If you look at the ternary Goldbach problem, it is known that every sufficiently large odd number can be written as $p_1+p_2+p_3$ with $p_i = n/3 + O(n^{11/20+\epsilon})$. https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02017

Comment: I think there has been more (computational) work on how to make $p-q$ as big as possible, than as small as possible.

Comment: Relevant OEIS sequence: https://oeis.org/A047160, "a(n) = smallest number m >= 0 such that n-m and n+m are both primes" - I was hoping for a pointer into the literature, but nothing there.

Answer (score 1):

The same method used to prove Chen's theorem produces the following:

Let $N$ be any even integer, then we have for sufficiently large $x$ that

\begin{aligned}
\#\{p\le x:p+N&\text{ is a product of at most two primes}\} \\
&>0.67{x\over\log^2x}\prod_{\substack{p|N\\p>2}}{p-1\over p-2}\prod_{p>2}\left(1-{1\over(p-1)^2}\right).
\end{aligned}

Comment: A result more along the OPs interest should be along the lines of, "for any sufficiently large $n$, we can write $n=p+q$ with $p$ prime and $q$ prime or semiprime such that $p-q=O(f(n))$" for some $f(n)$. Do you know what kind of result Chen's method can give in that direction? Can we at least get $f(n)=o(n)$?

Comment: Let $p_n$ be $n$'th prime. Then it is known that $p_{n+1}-p_n=O(p_n^\theta)$ for some $\theta<1$. The value of $\theta$ depends on subconvexity estimates of $\zeta\left(\frac12+it\right)$. More can be found in the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap)

Comment: If this was meant as a response to me - I don't see how that's relevant. Sure we have bounds on prime gaps but we want specifically pairs of primes which sum to the given $n$.

Comment: For that case, it seems unlikely to obtain any global bound better than $O(n)$. As $p+3$ is always even whenever $p$ is odd.

Comment: How is $p+3$ being even an obstruction, or at all relevant?

Comment: When $p$ is odd, $2n=p+3$ is surely even, and the difference is $p-3=2n+O(1)$.

Comment: Sure, there will be some pairs for which $p-q$ is large. The question is whether there will always be pairs for which it is small.

Comment: @Wojowu Well, we already know that there are infinitely many even numbers that can be expressed as $p+q$ such that $p,q$ are prime and $|p-q|\le246$ due to Polymath.

Comment: @TravorLZH That's also not directly relevant in any obvious way.

Answer (score -1):

This is only a partial answer. Write $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r\geq 0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$, which is well defined whenever $n>1$ if you assume Goldbach's conjecture. Then if I'm not mistaken $r_{0}(n)$ is reached when you apply this algorithm recursively: $u_{0}(n):=0$ and $u_{k+1}(n):=u_{k}(n)+2^{1_{2\not\mid n}}.3^{1_{3\not\mid n}}\frac{(\Omega(n-u_{k}(n))+\Omega(n+u_{k}(n)-2))+\vert\Omega(n-u_{k}(n))-\Omega(n+u_{k}(n))\vert}{2}$ and the latter fraction equals $0$. If you can prove rigorously that this algorithm stops in $O((\log n)^2)$ steps, you're done.